# Postgresql Nested functions

Tags: postgresql, function, nested

I'm trying to nest functions in postgresql, trying to extract a directory name (actually the third one) from a path.

My starting SQL code was :

```
SELECT "Path", regexp_matches("Path", '^([^/]*/){3}.*') FROM ...
```

Since the returned value of my regex is delimited by curly brace and double-quote (when containing spaces), I'm trying to remove theses delimiters by nesting functions :

```
SELECT "Path", right(regexp_matches("Path", '^([^/]*/){3}.*'),2) FROM
```

But I've the following error :

```
ERROR:  function right(text[], integer) does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT "Path", right(regexp_matches("Path", '^([^/]*/){3}.*'...
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
État SQL :42883
Caractère :17
```

I don't know how to format the expression in order to be accepted...

Of course, if someone can give me a way to get exactly the nth field of a string separated by slashes, I would be happy !

Comment: `right` does not take an array as first argument. What do you want to do?

Comment: "*Since the returned value of my regex is delimited by curly brace and double-quote*" That's because it's an array. So instead of parsing it as a string, use array notation to access the value at the index you want.

Comment: I miss an array was returned. So, `regexp_matches("Path", '^([^/]*/){3}.*'))[1]` works, thanks to all.